# Are class action settlements taxable as income in the United States?

Tags: united-states, taxes

In my case the settlement was a result of an insurance company lawsuit alleging that the insurance company overcharged its customers on a fee to its customers (including myself).

I'm thinking that this would effectively be a (forced) reimbursement. Am I correct in assuming that this event is not likely taxable?

It doesn't make a huge difference since the amount was under $10, but I am mostly just curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not a reimbursement. Monetary awards, including punitive damages, are taxable. The only exception is when the damages are your health (physical injuries/illness). You either report them as taxable income, or reduce your basis in the property to which the award refers.

See [this helpful publication from the IRS](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p4345.pdf).

Comment: I don't see anything in the document you reference to back up this statement. Repayments for overcharging don't seem to fall into any of the categories discussed in the article, and I don't see a blanket statement that all other categories are taxable. Naively, if a court orders someone to pay back money I have paid them out of after-tax income (for example if I paid for work that they didn't do) then I don't see how that could be taxable. isn't this the same?

Comment: Reparations for "injury" or "losses" should not be taxable. Did you claim a deduction for the loss that has been made good by restitution ?

A forgiven debt may be taxable as imputed income.  Similar case law for circumstances identical to yours should be referenced.

Comment: @mckenzm as I said - if property is involved then the award reduces your basis in the property.

Comment: @DJClayworth the blanket statement is IRC Sec. 62. Class action suit rewards are usually punitive damages, not cure for specific injury. When you get a monetary award in a class action suit - you only need to show that you're part of the class, you don't need to show any damage or injury caused to you personally. As such - your example is completely irrelevant.

Comment: This case is in fact a cure for a specific injury, i.e. an overcharge.